# Which Mono.Posix package should I include when building .NetCore app for Linux?

Tags: linux, .net-core, mono, posix

I'm building a .NetCore app to run in Linux environment.
I want to utilize some of the system calls exposed by Mono.Posix library.
I'm planning on conditionally compiling for Linux and using the default
libraries for Windows environments.

There are 2 possible packages I can install from NuGet Package Manager.

- Mono.Posix.NetStandard
- Mono.Posix-4.5

Which package should I be including?